# mysqlworkbench insercao de valores com INSERT INTO em uma tabela N:N

Tags: banco-de-dados, mysql, entidade-relacionamento

é possivel inserir mais de um genero na tabela livro_tem_genero?

exemplo do código que estou usando no mysql:

| livro | livro_tem_genero | genero |
| --- | --- | --- |
| id_livro | id_livro | id_genero |
| titulo | id_genero | nome |

=-=

tabela (1:n) *livro*:

```
 INSERT INTO livro (titulo) VALUES ('harry potter');
 INSERT INTO livro (titulo) VALUES ('mitologia nordica');
```

=-=

tabela (1:n) *genero*:

```
INSERT INTO genero (nome) VALUES ('Fantasia');

INSERT INTO genero (nome) VALUES ('Ficção científica');
```

=-=

tabela (n:n) *livro_tem_genero*:

**minha duvida é nessa tabela, é possível inserir 2 generos no mesmo livro ?**

```
INSERT INTO livro_tem_genero (id_livro,id_genero) VALUES (?,?);
```

[entidade relacionamento_bd.img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Rj8E.png)

Comment: Com um relacionamento `n:m` sim, não duplique perguntas, como já sugerido na sua [pergunta original](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/586876/mysql-workbench-%c3%a9-possivel-inserir-dados-em-tabelas-nn#comment1022696_586876), incluindo link da documentação oficial que fornece exemplos e explicações do uso. Se tiver alguma dúvida que vá além do que a documentação orienta então edite a pergunta original e aguarde o processo de avaliação de 5 diferentes usuários (na fila de analises) para reabertura da pergunta. Os comentários aqui serão bloqueados para que continue na pergunta original.